# How can I use an Intent into a recyclerview into a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

This is the Adapter, but when I click the `cardView`, the app restart.
I tried to use `view.getContext()` instead `context` in the Holder but tha app restart too.
What I have to do?
And Where I have to put the `@Override onActivityResult` if I want to use a `startActivityForResult`

```
public class estudioEdit_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<estudioEdit_Adapter.Holder> {
public List<Estudio> lista;
public Context context;

public estudioEdit_Adapter(List<Estudio> lista, Context context){
    this.lista=lista;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_estudio_edit,parent,false);
    Holder contendor= new Holder(view);
    return contendor;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder contendor, int position) {
    contendor.lblNombre.setText(this.lista.get(position).getNombre());
    contendor.lblCentroEstudios.setText(this.lista.get(position).getCentroEstudios());
    contendor.context=this.context;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return lista.size();
}

public static class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView lblNombre, lblCentroEstudios;
    CardView cvEstudio;
    Context context;

    public Holder(View view){
        super(view);
        lblNombre =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblNombreEstudio);
        lblCentroEstudios =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblCentroEstudio);
        cvEstudio=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cvEstudio);

        cvEstudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EstudioEditar.class);
                Activity a=(Activity) context;
                a.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: App is restarting means your app is crashing , you are use wrong method to call the intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `context` because its a null value when you fire `startIntent` so you need to hold `reference` on `context` on your `view holder context`. You can also do below thing :-

```
   cvEstudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, EstudioEditar.class);
            Activity a=(Activity) context;
            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

or you need to pass context to your viewholder

**fragment**

```
@Override
public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_estudio_edit,parent,false);
    Holder contendor= new Holder(view,getActivity());
    return contendor;
}
```

**viewholder**

```
 public Holder(View view, Context context){
        super(view);
        lblNombre =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblNombreEstudio);
        lblCentroEstudios =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblCentroEstudio);
        cvEstudio=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cvEstudio);

        cvEstudio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EstudioEditar.class);
                Activity a=(Activity) context;
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: thanks, this works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, EstudioEditar.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried that but the app generates an error and restarts

Comment: paste your errors

Answer (score 1):

You have to like this, It will help you...

Some I have also faced this kind of issue, so am handling in following way

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(Holder contendor, int position) {
    contendor.lblNombre.setText(this.lista.get(position).getNombre());
    contendor.lblCentroEstudios.setText(this.lista.get(position).getCentroEstudios());

    contendor.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {            
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, EstudioEditar.class));
                }
            });
}
```

and then remove this line

```
contendor.context=this.context;
```

because of already you assign the context value in your constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can use any View to it. `getContext()` method provides almost activity methods because Activity extends Context.

```
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```